# Very simple jQuery rollover

Tags: jquery, rollover

I made a very simple [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) `img` rollover function inspired by this one:
http://www.smileycat.com/miaow/archives/000224.php.

It just check all the `img`s that contain `_off` in their name and swap them with an `img` with the same name but "_on" instead of "_off".

Since I can't use background `img`s in my layout, I feel that's an handy solution.
But I've got the feeling that the swapping is not smooth, like if the function runs slow.
What do you think?
Are there ways to optimize it?

Here is the code:

```
    function roll_over() {
        $("img[src*='_off']").hover(
            function() {
                var stringa = $(this).attr("src");
                var stringa = stringa.replace("_off", "_on");
                $(this).attr("src", stringa);
            },
            function() {
                var stringa = $(this).attr("src");
                var stringa = stringa.replace("_on", "_off");
                $(this).attr("src", stringa);
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: When are you calling this function?

Comment: I call the function on document.ready

Answer (score 2):

Your code is bad. Why?

1. It will fail when you'll have image like this: `...src="/images/my_office.png"...`
2. You use JS for something that is so primitive that can be done in pure CSS
3. The `*_on` images will be loaded on `mouseover` event so you won't see any image for a while.

How to fix all of these issues? Use [CSS Sprites](http://www.google.pl/search?hl=pl&q=css+sprites&btnG=Szukaj+w+Google&lr=).

1. Create image like this one: http://www.digart.pl/gfx/ico/s/fb.gif
2. HTML code: `<a href="..." id="myId">blah</a>` (of cource you don't have to use `A` element).
3. CSS code:

   ```
   #myId {
       display: inline-block; /* or block, or even inline with correct line-height */
       width: 33px;
       height: 20px;
       background: url(/path/to/img) 0 0 no-repeat;
   }
   #myId:hover {
       background-position: 50% 0;
   }
   ```

If you still want to automatize whole process then use JS only to change background position instead of image.

Comment: +1 CSS sprites will really make this a lot easier and quicker.

Comment: I am not sure why, but the OP says this in their question: "...I can't use background imgs in my layout."  That may be why they are trying to do it this way.

Comment: @Buggabill: Ops... my fault. I didn't notice this.

Answer (score 1):

I found a good function here 
http://webdevel.blogspot.com/2008/04/rollover-images-with-jquery.html

```
$("#mylink img").hover(
 function()
 {
  this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
 },
 function()
 {
  this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
 }
);
```

I just specify the id or class of imgs

Answer (score 0):

Repeatedly doing `$("img[src*='_off']")` is inefficient. It means the browser is having to search everything on a page when you roll over. You should include [jQuery Lint](http://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Lint) for information about optimisation...

Comment: I would agree that repeatedly calling this function on a mouseover event would be unnecessary, inefficient, and not advised.  If they are calling it on the page load, it is a different matter entirely.

Comment: Also defining `stringa` variable twice??

Comment: So please can you give me an hand in modify it?
BTW I can't use background replacement because I resize the imgs

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
// Add an image to your page as:
// <img src="button.png" class="rollover">

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    initRollovers();
});
function initRollovers() {  
    // Assign a class to the images you want to have as roll-over enabled.
    // Example:
    // <img src="button.png" class="rollover">
    // NOTE: No "dot" when setting the class on the image... But jQuery needs the .dot in order to search for classes in this script:
    var classIdentifier = ".rollover";

    // This example assumes that only the "on" state has a suffix:
    // button.png
    // button_on.png

    // If you have a suffix for both states, edit them here:
    // button_off.png
    // button_on.png
    // ... would be edited as:
    // var offSuffix = "_off.png";
    // var onSuffix = "_on.png";

    var offSuffix = ".png";
    var onSuffix = "_on.png";

    $(classIdentifier).each(function () {

        var obj = $(this);
        var mySrcOff = obj.attr("src");
        var mySrcOn = mySrcOff.replace(offSuffix, onSuffix);
        obj.mouseout(function() {
            $(this).attr("src", mySrcOff);
        });
        obj.mouseover(function() {
            $(this).attr("src", mySrcOn);
        });

        // Preload Off State
        $('<img />').attr('src', mySrcOn).appendTo('body').css('display','none');

    });
}

</script>
```

.